# Aplicar uma regex no resultado de um select

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, substring

Estou fazendo uma consulta para pegar todos os projetos que estejam sendo executados:

```
SELECT p.id FROM projetos p WHERE p.status LIKE 'Execução'
```

Um exemplo do resultado:

```
COD00012347
COD00012348
COD01212349
COD00123410
COD00123411
```

Gostaria de aplicar uma regex afim de que o meu resultado fosse apenas os números (desconsiderando os `0` a esquerda):

```
12347
12348
1212349
123410
123411
```

Tentei aplicar a função `SUBSTRING()` mas não tive bons resultados. Estou aprendendo SQL ainda, o que posso fazer??

Comment: Mas qual foi o problema que você encontrou com a função substring? Já pensou em utilizar a função RIGHT?

Comment: @anonimo a qnt de zeros pode variar por exemplo.

Comment: Se quer apenas os 6 últimos caracteres, talvez `RIGHT(coluna, 6)` funcione.

Comment: @anonimo ainda assim esse 6 pode variar. Editei a pergunta pra mostrar um resultado mais específico.

Comment: Se você precisa desse número separado, não seria melhor armazená-lo em uma coluna diferente?

Comment: @anonimo não tenho permissão de escrita.. como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Caso seu id seja essa quantidade fixa, não vejo a necessidade de regex, basta dar um cast pra inteiro que os zeros a esquerda irão desaparecer após o substring, exemplo:

```
select cast (SUBSTRING('COD00012347',4,8) as int )  -- resulta em 12347
```

Atualização

caso as letras no inicio também possuam uma quantidade dinamica, aí fica mais fácil com regex mesmo usando `patindex`, exemplo:

```
select substring('COD00012347',PATINDEX('%[1-9]%','COD00012347'),len('COD00012347')) -- regex pega o index do primeiro numero de 1 a 9, depois a quantidade de caracteres da string conforme sua dica
```

Comment: Isso me ajuda! Pois no lugar do `8` posso colocar `len(atributo)`.

Comment: mas oq posso colocar no lugar do quatro para que ele comece a contar a partir da última letra??

Comment: aí nesse caso acho melhor usar regex mesmo, vou atualizar a resposta

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente!